# PHP Email not being sent, what's wrong?

Tags: php, jquery, email

I have an html form with information being sent to this script and everything is working perfectly, except the email being sent... It appears to send (if statement goes through). but I don't receive anything. A few days ago I was receiving emails, where all data would be "Array[]", but now for some reason it's not working.

```
<?php
echo "<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>";

if (!empty($_POST) && $_POST['email-address'] != null)
{
    $inquireType = $_POST['inquiry-type'];
    $firstName = $_POST['first-name'];
    $lastName = $_POST['last-name'];
    $email = $_POST['email-address'];
    $businessName = $_POST['business-name'];
    $information = $_POST['extra-information'];

    $message = "" . $inquireType . ' INQUIRIE FROM: ' . $firstName . ' ' . $lastName . "\r\n" .
        'Email: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
        'Business Name: ' . $businessName . "\r\n" .
        'Additional Information: ' . $information;

    $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['email-address']) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['email-address']) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "CC: bud@budbroesky.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

    mail('myemail@gmail.com', "Inquirie", $message, $headers);

    if (mail('myemail@gmail.com', 'Inquirie From ' . $firstName, $message, $headers))
    {
        echo "<div style='position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: green;'><br><br><p align='center'><font size='5rem' face='Montserrat' color='white'>Inquiry Successfully Sent! Expect a reply from me shortly.";
    }
    else {
        echo "<div style='position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: red;'><br><br><p align='center'><font size='5rem' face='Montserrat' color='white'>Inquiry Not Sent, something must have went wrong...";
    }
}
else {
    echo "<div style='position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: darkred;'><br><br><p align='center'><font size='5rem' face='Montserrat' color='white'>Inquiry Not Sent, something must have went wrong...";
}

 ?>
```

Comment: Did you check your Spam folder?

Comment: R u getting Inquiry Not Sent, something must have went wrong???

Comment: I constantly check my Spam folder, and no, it's showing that the email is going through...

Comment: And u r getting  Successfully Sent! Expect a reply from me shortly.??

Comment: There are several things that could go wrong with `mail()` function. Refer this SO question, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail)

Comment: The actual issue was my hosting service required the $header's "From" to be a registered email (i.e. contact@yourdomain.com). My code is now working perfectly! budbroesky.com

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$headers` is a string and you are using `implode("\r\n", $headers)` while sending email. This will throw a warning.

Replace `implode("\r\n", $headers)` with `$headers` since you are already concatenating `\r\n` while preparing the header string.

Comment: I forgot to change that, saw that as I posted, but it's still not sending even without imploding...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have not provided credentials for email account. I have used the code below (in C#) in my app. I wish it can help you.

```
            //Configure an SmtpClient to send the mail.
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            client.EnableSsl = true; //only enable this if your provider requires it
            //Setup credentials to login to our sender email address ("UserName", "Password")
            NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("mymail@gmail.com", "mypassword");
            client.Credentials = credentials;
```